# Error in self-defined loss : ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Hey I have defined a loss function on my own (no using the built-in loss functions from tensorflow. My goal is to minimize this loss function to do a unspervised learning. unfortunately, I was stuck in this error:

```
optimizer_1.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars=zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
  File "/home/jxy/miniconda3/envs/EKGCompetition2022/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 640, in apply_gradients
    grads_and_vars = optimizer_utils.filter_empty_gradients(grads_and_vars)
  File "/home/jxy/miniconda3/envs/EKGCompetition2022/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_v2/utils.py", line 73, in filter_empty_gradients
    raise ValueError(f"No gradients provided for any variable: {variable}. "
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (
```

my code is like:

```
#@tf.function
    def train_step(input, time):
        #input shape(1,11,5,3)
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            output = model(input)  
            input1 = input.numpy()
            print('oooooooooooo', time, output)
            a=input1[0,-1,:,0]
            b = input1[0,-1,:,1]
            output = output.numpy()
            Matrix = loss.Output2codingMatrix(Output=output)
            communication_loss = loss.loss_Sumrate(a, Matrix, b)
            communication_loss = tf.convert_to_tensor(communication_loss)
        gradients = tape.gradient(communication_loss, model.trainable_variables)
        optimizer_1.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars=zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
```

beforehand I have defined

```
optimizer_1 = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
```

communication_loss is a self defined loss related to a,b and matrix.
Think the problem lies on the relation of communication loss and variables
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to include your actual loss function in the question. Are you sure your loss is differentiable?

Comment: They are using `output.numpy()`, so this will not work.